# Whether DOM property will work for Phone Gap android?

Tags: javascript, android, html, cordova, dom

I am working on a Phonegap android project.

I would like to know whether the DOM property will work for Phone Gap or not.Because,I tried implementing a condition such as

```
if(results.rows.item(val[1]).COLUMN_NAME==="")
{
    document.getElementById("ID").src="img/abc.png";
    console.log("abc image to be changed"+val[1]);
}
else
{

    document.getElementById("ID").src="img/abc1.png";
    console.log("no change "+val[1]);
}
```

**HTML CODE:**

I tried executing the program in **2 of the following cases** in HTML

**CASE 1:**

```
<div id="ID" > <img src="img/abc1.png"  onclick="abc()" /></div>
```

**CASE 2:**

```
 <div id="ID" > <img src=""  onclick="abc()" /></div>
```

when i run the program the Console statement is being displayed,but there is no change in the image.

**AM I RIGHT IN THE WAY OF IMPLEMENTATION?**

please guide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

div doesn't have the attribute src. so you need to give the id to img tag to change the src of image like that:

```
<div> <img src="img/abc1.png" id="ID" onclick="abc()" /></div>
```

Or you can change the image by the innerHTML property like this:

```
document.getElementById("ID").innerHTML = '<img src="img/abc.png" onclick="abc()" />';
```

Use any one which you want.

Comment: MIss poo,thank you,i selected the innerhtml property and it worked.

Comment: well,MIss poo,IF YOU KNOW,please let me know how to use the hide property in javascript/DOM.i want to hide a slide

Comment: use this code: `document.getElementById("id_of_slider").style.display = 'none';`

Comment: i used the following code `if(value[0]===""){ console.log("no value"); document.getElementById(id).style.display = 'none';        document.getElementById("ID").hide();  }  else { console.log("yes value"); }`

Comment: `.hide()`  is the function of jQuery not javascript so use it `document.getElementById("ID").style.display = 'none';` and remove the `document.getElementById("ID").hide();`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29727/discussion-between-user-and-miss-poo)

Comment: MIss poo,I require your help on these questions, Please do the needful.[Q1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16684159/how-to-code-a-stickyfooter-in-css) **and** [Q2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16663194/css-of-a-slide-in-swipe-view)

Answer (score 1):

div tag does't have any src attribute .src attribute is img tag property . so get that id inside img tag . then only you can change the src attribute