# CSS of a slide in swipe view

Tags: html, css, design-patterns, responsive-design

I am working in Phone Gap using java script,html and css. I have implemented a swipeview using [this](http://www.idangero.us/sliders/swiper/).

my doubt is how should the **CSS** be.The **CSS** i implemented is as follows.

```
.swiper-threshold {
width:100%;
height:350px;
margin-top:40px;
text-align:left;
line-height:20px;
font-size: 15px;
text-align:justify;
text-justify:inter-word;
}

.swiper-threshold .swiper-slide{
width:auto;
height:350px;
margin-top:2%;
margin-left:0;
padding-right:0%;
text-align:left;
line-height:20px;
font-size: 15px;
text-align:justify;
text-justify:inter-word;
}
```

the sliding movement is from left to right.when it reaches the last slide.the movement reverses. 
when,I change `margin-left:0;` from 0 to say 5...as and when I slide the left space gets on adding up the last slide is seen for half of the screen.

but,when i give `margin-left:0;` all are stuck to the left margin.

**html coding:**

```
 <div id="swipe_body">
    <div class="swiper-container swiper-threshold">
        <div class="swiper-wrapper" id="swiper-wrapper">

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**SWIPER-SLIDE creation**

```
            var val = k+1;
            var superdiv = document.getElementById('swiper-wrapper');
            var newdiv =  mySwiper.createSlide('div');
            newdiv.append();
            var divIdName = 'swiper-slide'+val;
            console.log("div name: "+divIdName);
            newdiv.setAttribute('id',divIdName);
            newdiv.className="swiper-slide";
            superdiv.appendChild(newdiv);
            var cnt = '<div id="container'+val+'" class="container">values</div>';
            document.getElementById(divIdName).innerHTML=cnt;
            console.log("processsing parameter loop ");
```

what should i give such that n-number of swipes the slides should be the same position-middle of the screen.

please,guide me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you're trying to get your slider to sit in the middle of the screen, but in doing so you're adding margin to the slider elements itself.  Is that correct?

If so, the reason you're having trouble is that the slider implementation itself uses the margins to position the slides during movement left/right.

In order to control the spacing around the slider, the easiest bet is to wrap it in another div which you can traget directly.

So, taking the dimensions/etc that you've set up, your HTML would instead look like this:

```
<div class="slider-positioner">
    <div id="swipe_body">
        <div class="swiper-container swiper-threshold">
            <div class="swiper-wrapper" id="swiper-wrapper">

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

You can then drop this CSS in to target that new div and push it into the middle (either using amrgin: auto as I have done below, or using set margin amounts as you seem to suggest you would like):

```
.slider-positioner{
    display: block;
    width: 550px; //set this to the width of your slider
    height: 350px;
    margin: 0px auto;
}
```

Comment: johnkavanagh,yes thank you....i have solved this problem..No,this `margin: 0px auto;` did not work...but i had made changes in the default css of the swiper. **how to add the swiper identification.what is imporatant to add it and how?**

Comment: Ah, the margin: auto trick to get an element centered very much depends on what other styles the element is inheriting (and likewise: the parent element).  Glad to hear you've worked it out!  Not quite sure what your additional question is, does it relate to the original CSS question or would that be better opened as an additional question tagged as 'javascript'?

Comment: johnkavanagh,please let me know your views on [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16734084/how-to-add-the-swipe-view-identifier-or-pagination-in-java-script)..please guide