# how to code a stickyfooter in css?

Tags: html, css

I want a header,body and footer.I have coded it.when I alter the codes the footer either sits below the body when i give it like this

**HTML CODE:**

```
<div id="body" style="background-image:url(img/bg.png);" class="body">
<div id="title" class="title">
         <h1><strong></strong></h1>
    </div>

    <div id="desc" class="desc">
    <p style="desc p"></p>
    </div>
 </div> 

<div id="footer" style="background-image:url(img/bottom_bar.png);" class="footer">
<div><h6 class="footer h6">2011-FOOOTER</h6><a href=""><img src="img/info.png" alt="" /></a></div>
</div>
```

**CSS CODE:**

```
.body
 {
float:left; float:left; width:100%; height:100%; min-height: 100%; overflow-y: scroll;
 }

.title
{
width:85%; font-weight:bold; float:left; font-size:20px; margin-top:3%; margin-bottom:2%; margin-left:5%; color:#FFFFFF;
}

.desc
{
  width:90%; font-size:15px; margin-left:5%; margin-right:5%; float:left; color: #FFFFFF; overflow:auto; text-align:justify; line-height:18px;
}

.desc p
{
margin-top:0; 
}
```

**CSS CODE of footer:**

```
 .footer
    {
         float:left; width:100%; line-font-size:15px; padding:0px; bottom:0px; height:25px;  font-size:18px;
    }
```

when I code it as below,the footer sits on the body and when you go down you can see the text below the footer

```
.footer
{
     float:left; width:100%; position:absolute; line-font-size:15px; padding:0px; bottom:0px; height:25px;  font-size:18px;
}
```

I want the footer to be fixed to the bottom of the screen and want the text to scroll without the scroll bar.

Could someone suggest what is the mistake I have done and where?

Comment: Reference http://dave-woods.co.uk/100-height-layout-using-css/

Comment: @AvinVarghese this isn't solving my problem.Anyways,thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this styles for which to see scrollbar just remove overflow:hidden in body

```
html,
body {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    height:100%;
    overflow:hidden;
}
#wrapper {
    min-height:100%;
    position:relative;

}
#header {
    background:#ededed;
    padding:10px;
}
#content {
    padding-bottom:100px; /* Height of the footer element */

}
#footer {
    background:#ffab62;
    width:100%;
    height:100px;
    position:fixed;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Sure you will get footer pushed under body with 100% height of body, with no space for footer to stay in your view, you need to solve it, anyway this question is so common, your words maybe not helped you, simply you need to search about "Sticky Footer" a lot of questions answered here or simply with magic of Google you can see :
http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/
and http://www.cssstickyfooter.com/

And learn about it.
Good luck.

Comment: Al-Mothafar,thank you,I have fixed the problem partially fixing the height of the body in pixels.I find the same in the links suggested by you.So,please suggest me a way to solve it by fixing the height in %. As I am using this for mobile,as and when the device changes,so will the px height. **please suggest me a way to set the height in %**

Comment: I would like to get a solution for another problem with css [CHECK THIS!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16663194/css-of-a-slide-in-swipe-view)

Comment: @user the links that I gave you set `height` to 100% and `min-height` to 100%, the fixed value with pixels is for footer `height` and same value must be for `padding-bottom` and negative same value `margin-top` , so really I don't see where the issue left, since links already using % not px, do u want `height` for footer with % also??

Comment: Al-Mothafar,the problem has not solved using `float:left; width:100%; min-height: 100%; height: auto !important; height: 100%; overflow:auto;` i used for the body and for the footer `width:100%;  position:absolute; padding:0px; margin:0px; bottom:0px; height:100%; line-height:45px; font-size:12px; color:#FFFFFF; text-align:center; float:left; height:25px; line-height:25px;
`

Comment: why u use `float:left` with `width:100%` what the point with float here?, and about `position:absolute; ` its destroy everything. try remove floating and positioning from footer and body, and fix ur padding and margin to fit with css in links.

Answer (score 1):

in the footer class

Instead of

```
position:absolute;
```

use

```
position:fixed;
```

this should work